# How to change the backGround color of App in App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to change the backGround  of an App in App Store ?

like this ...

[image]

please help me...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming – it's about custom branding in the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Only select apps qualify for that by Apple. It is fully up to Apple to choose which apps get special branding.

Comment: means FB is not qualify by Apple  to get special branding ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the requirements are. It's 100% up to Apple. FB could have denied it. The whole process is really only known to app who get it offered to them.

Comment: if you can tell me this http://forums.imore.com/general-developer-discussion/328402-how-set-up-background-image-app-listing-app-store.html

Comment: @subbaraj What do you mean?

Comment: Hey sorry don't take wrong i checked in google ,i found it .But it was not understand that why i posted to you

Comment: Basically what they mean is it's not possible. You have to contact Apple to see if they will do it for you. MOST of the time you get denied.